# Evitar push de um branch específico para o remote errado

Tags: git

Olá,

Alguém me sabe instruir sobre como evitar fazer asneiras com o git? No
seguinte aspeto:

Tenho um projeto com 2 "remotes" configurados (imagine-se um da empresa -
empresa - e outro privado - meuservidor). Mantenho um "branch" que
sincronizo com o repositório da empresa (master -> empresa/master) e outro
que sincronizo com a minha versão do projeto que é ligeiramente diferente
(meu -> meuservidor/master).

Agora: como é que configuro o git para me impedir de fazer burrices e
fazer "push" do meu "branch" pessoal para o servidor da empresa, por
exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro,

Configure o push:

```
git config --global push.default simple
```

Depois, use o "track" com sua branch:

```
git branch master --set-upstream-to=empresa/master
git status         # mostra conexão entre master e empresa/master
```

Depois,

```
git checkout master
git push                      # Para empresa
git push meuservidor master   # Para seu servidor privado
```

Você pode criar e usar alias:

```
git config --local alias.push-empresa "push empresa master"
git config --local alias.push-servidor "push meuservidor master"

git push-empresa
git push-servidor
```

Comment: Boa ideia essa dos aliases.

Comment: Excelente ideia! Simples e funcional.

Answer (score 0):

Se você utiliza Git com Windows existe uma extensão para Powershell bem interessante chamada posh-git, você pode fazer o download via Chocolatey [aqui](https://chocolatey.org/packages/poshgit).
Essa extensão mostra o nome do branch corrente no prompt, ou seja, não é mais necessário digitar git status para verificar qual o branch corrente.

Comment: Uso linux, mas há algo que faz o mesmo em linux também. Não serve para o que pretendo, embora pudesse ajudar. Acho que vou, simplesmente, confiar em fazer sempre só "git push" e nunca indicar explicitamente o "branch" errado.